# How UITableView delegates works?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, protocols

In my view I have used UITableView, I have set delegate and data source with file owner in nib. And in my class .h file I have conforms to the protocol like below...

eg:

```
@interface test : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
...
...
}
```

Everything works fine... delegate methods are all called properly... Now my question is why we are adding "UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource" in .h. without that also I'm getting those calls. What is the use of this?

thanx

Comment: adding what? protocols (UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource)?

Comment: Yes. Check now that rectangular brackets cutted those line...

Comment: It means that you class supports those methods from UITableViewDelegate. And, actually without adding them you can't start typing methods like -tableView:numberInRows etc with autocompletion.

Comment: You should not be adding the two protocols to the .h file. You should add them to a class extension in the .m file instead. There is no reason for outside classes to know that your view controller happens to be a table view delegate and data source. That is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For two reasons I guess:

1. This is for Compiler to tell that you will implement the datasource and delegate methods and compiler gives warning if you dont implement them.
2. AutoComplete on these methods work only if you add like that in header files

Answer (score 2):

if in your .xib file you are setting your datasource and delegate to file owner,I think there is no need to do that.

Comment: Sarfaraz, I guess you are wrong. Setting via Interface Builder replaces the `tableView.delegate = self;` and `tableView.dataSource = self;`. As Puneet says, this is for the compiler, autocomplete, and classes interfaces should have this.

Answer (score 2):

**Apple** defines **[Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)** as :

> In the world of object-oriented programming, it’s important to be able
>   to define a set of behavior that is expected of an object in a given
>   situation. As an example, a table view expects to be able to
>   communicate with a data source object in order to find out what it is
>   required to display. This means that the data source must respond to a
>   specific set of messages that the table view might send.
>
> Objective-C allows you to define protocols, which declare the methods
>   expected to be used for a particular situation.

To know more about TableView's Protocol Reference, you can take a look at :

1. [UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
2. [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

if you write `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`it just means your class `conformsToProtocol` to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

You can alloc a `test`(Your test class) and invoke this

```
[testObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITableViewDelegate)];
```

it will return `true`.

**else**

it will return `false` . BTW unless you write tableviewDelegate method it won't autocomplete for you

**You question is why we are adding "UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource" in .h. without that also I'm getting those calls.**

because it does like this.

```
if ( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cellWillDisplay...)] )
{
      [delegate cellWillDisplay...]; //Apple gives you call
}
```

YEAH, your class implement the method `cellWillDisplay...` 
then you get the call!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create or use `UITableView` programatically instead of `nib` file then you need to specify   `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` in .h file.

And when you want to use UITableView in .nib file rather than programaticaly than you dont need to specify it in .h file.

Comment: I dont understand this point. If you create UITableView programmatically and you dont state the decalaration in header file like that, do you bound  to get compilation/runtime error?

Comment: @Puneet - when you create UITableView programmatically , you have to state the decalaration in header file like that

Comment: Otherwise it results in error? Are you sure about it?

Answer (score 1):

```
See this url for reference..

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Also In this url we will use the methods frequently are

– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

  This will set Height

– tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:

 This will act as cellback for ui actions you are doing in table

– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:

 usually we will add uiviews as table header

– tableView:viewForFooterInSection:

 usually we will add uiviews as table footer

– tableView:heightForHeaderInSection

 will set height to section header 

– tableView:heightForFooterInSection

 will set height to section footer
```

Comment: This is what the delegate will do